# Can we define some like a "dimensionality" to infinite sets?

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory

Consider, for example the following sets:

1. ${x,y,z} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which $x^2+y^2<1$
2. ${x,y,z} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which $x^2<1$
3. $\mathbb{R}^3$

Of course, the cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$ of all. Also their volume is infinite.

But, I intuitive feel, somehow there should some... measurement, some terminology exist, which would somehow differentiate some like a "1-dimensional infinity" of (1), the "2-dimensional infinity" of (2) and the "3-dimensional infinity" of 3.

I suspect, it may have more to do with analysis as with set theory.

Does any similar, well-defined terminology exist to make a distinction between (1), (2) and (3)?

---

*Edit:* the "dimensionality" of the points closer as 1 to the $x^2=y$ parabola should be also 1.

Comment: The cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$ - that's not necessarily the same thing as $\aleph_1$. The statement that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), and is *independent* - it can neither be proved or disproved from [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Comment: you can do intersections with affine subspaces and check the measure. if there is a subspace of a certain dimension so that the measure of the intersection is finite then you have some thing to categorize.

Comment: Convex sets have a "recession cone" consisting of all directions that you can follow "to infinity" without leaving the convex set. Maybe you could look at the dimension of the affine hull of the recession cone or something.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Oh, thanks. I've seen it always from a practical, engineer viewpoint. :-) I have made already a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1159395/111704) about a similar topic (can we define a set with $\aleph_1 < 2^{\aleph_0}$ cardinality if we have ZFC + not-CH). I think we can assume CH from a practicality viewpoint in the sense of this question. What is the case for the set of the points closer as 1 distance from the $x=y^2$ parabola? The subspace-based definition probably won't work, I think it should be "1-dimensional" like the set (1).

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with set theory, as you suspected, so I've removed the set-theory tag.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok, thanks.

Comment: @peterh: Why does your intuition tell you that $(1)$ is one-dimensional? This is an infinite cylinder without it's boundary and to describe a point in this cylinder, you need to give me three parameters - the height ($z$), the distance $\rho$ from the $z$-axis and the angle which the point makes with respect to the positive $x$-axis. From this point of view ("freedom degrees count") it should be a three-dimensional object and indeed it is a three-dimensional manifold (being an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first question would be: what is the purpose of distinguishing these three sets? From the point of topology, the three sets in (1), (2) and (3) are homeomorphic and from the point of differential calculus they are also diffeomoprhic.

Distinguishing them via their boundary is also difficult. The boundary of (1) is a cylinder, which has dimension 2 and hence codimension 1. This would correspond to the "1-dimensional infinity". However, the boundary of (2) are two planes, which have also codimension 1. On the other hand $\mathbb R^3$ has no boundary, which would be 0-dimensional and hence have codimension 3.

Most invariants in mathematics have been created to distinguish objects with some application in mind. Topological dimension, for example, answers the question which open subsets of euclidean space can be locally homeomorphic. It is difficult to find notions for distinguishing objects, without a use in mind.

Comment: It relates to my [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123912/what-is-the-color-number-of-the-3d-space-if-we-allow-only-convex-regions) question. I think, some "color number" could be defined also for 3 dimensions if we would reduce the allowed regions to the sets like (2).

Comment: Via the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (\tan x, y, z)$, the set $x^2 < \pi/2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$. And I believe this map would preserve convex sets, although I have not checked the details. Would this not present a problem?